# Is it acceptable to use var $this = $(this); or is there a better/more accepted way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it acceptable to use var $this = $(this); or is there a better/more accepted way?

The only reason I ask is my text editor doesn't seem to like it. I'm assuming it's because $this could be used for something in another language rather than Jquery.

My code looks something like this:

```
var $this;
$('.element').each(function () {
  $this = $(this);
});
```

Apologies if this belongs in code review, but I didn't get much help there.

Comment: Its acceptable. However important question What you going to do with `$this` after initialization? Also you are using _ID selector_ so whats the use of `.each()` remember IDs must be unique.

Comment: i wouldnt recommend doing it mate, anything called `this` is used in a scope of some sort, your `$(this)` var is being used inside the `.each()` function and you are bringing it outside of the `each` scope and giving it a `$this` name, later on in your code you will see this var of yours and might mistaken it with the `this` var of the scope you are in, it will make it much easier to handle if you just call it something else

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "acceptable"? What is acceptable for you might not be acceptable for me, so this sounds like a subjective question.

Comment: @banana: are you advising against `$this` or against using a free variable? Using `var $this = $(this);` is not an uncommon pattern.

Comment: The whole point of your block of code looks wrong.  There's no reason to use `.each()` on an id selector.  There's only one match and you're only storing one variable.  `var $this = $('#element');` works just fine.  I personally prefer to use a name like `self` or `item` rather than `$this` because I think it inteferes with readability of `this`, but that's just a personal opinion on code style.

Comment: @FelixKling i am advising against including a 'this' in a variable name that exists outside of the context where this var would be set. he names `$this` a variable that exists outside of the `each` function, it will most definitely cause confusion later when he will use this var in a different scope and will think that it represents the `$(this)` of that other scope

Comment: The `var $this` should be brought inside the loop; it makes no sense outside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code snippet looks more like a bug in the making than a code style example. I'll assume what you meant was:

```
$('.element').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  ...
});
```

And yes, it's perfectly acceptable. As you can [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp):

> Variable names must begin with a letter
>
> Variable names can also begin with $ and _(1) (but we will not use it)

---

Now, as for the goal: it's a matter of readability -- many people who work with jQuery find that prefixing their jQuery object variables with `$name` is easier to read. For example, this makes it easier to see at a glance what is a jQuery object and what is not:

```
var $this = $(this);
var $myVariable = $(".class1.class2:not(#exlusionId)");
```

Generally speaking you only need another reference to `this` when you're using it within enclosed function's closures. It's more common to see it used with longer, possibly non-trivial selectors, as above. The above of course is just as understandable as:

```
var element = $(this);
var myVariable = $(".class1.class2:not(#exlusionId)");
```

It's mostly a matter of habit and/or personal preference which way you go

---

The case in which it becomes a nuisance is when you have non-javascript mixed in. For example, it's all too common to see this nasty, nasty construct in a webpage source file with PHP parsing enabled:

```
var myJavascriptVariable = javascriptFunctionCall(<%php callSomePhp($phpVariables); %>);
```

Don't mix the dollarcase prefix in in there as it quickly becomes *very* difficult to see what's going on. Or *even better*, don't mix PHP in your javascript at all

---

(1) The `_` or sometimes `__` (double-underscore) prefix is usually used as a prefix to denote 'private' fields within objects

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While others were technically correct you've explained it beautifully.

Comment: @Jake: If you just wanted to know whether the `var $this = $(this);` is valid *syntax*, you could have executed the code.

Comment: @FelixKling At the moment my code is very basic, later on when it's more complex it may cause an issue, which this answer has explained.

Answer (score 1):

It is acceptable, but not in the way you used it.

This is the correct approach:

```
$('.element').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
});
```

That is, declare the variable *inside* the function, it should never be shared across functions.